# Insert trigger fires without considering the if condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

```
CREATE TABLE Account(
    account_no int,
    balance real,
    type_code int,
    branch_no int,
    Bcode int,
    customer_no int,

    CONSTRAINT account_pk PRIMARY KEY (account_no),
    CONSTRAINT check_balance CHECK (balance>=0)
);

alter TRIGGER tr_check_accounts_in_accountTBL
ON account INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @count int
DECLARE @bcode int
DECLARE @cusNo int

SELECT @bcode=bcode,@cusNo=customer_no
FROM inserted;

SELECT @count=COUNT(a.account_no)
FROM account a
WHERE a.bcode=@bcode AND a.customer_no = @cusNo
print @count;

IF(@count<=5)
    commit transaction
ELSE
        rollback transaction

END

INSERT INTO account(account_no,balance,type_code,bcode,branch_no,customer_no)
VALUES(1,60000,1,1,1,1);
```

When I try to insert the data to above Account table, trigger fires and rollback the transaction always. I can not understand why. can anyone please to explain 
thank you.

Error shows as below:

> Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

Comment: You need to rewrite your trigger - you're assuming it always has just a single row in `Inserted` - this is **NOT** the case! If you insert more than one row, `Inserted` will contain **more than ONE row** and your assignment `SELECT @bcode=bcode,@cusNo=customer_no
FROM inserted;` will arbitrarily pick one of those rows (and ignore the rest). Your trigger **needs to deal** with multiple rows in `Inserted`

Comment: Also, since you're using an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger, it's up to you to actually **do the `INSERT`** in the trigger. I don't see that happening anywhere ..... after the `INSERT`, you should not call `COMMIT` - that will happen automatically. Just use `ROLLBACK` if you want to abort the operation.

Comment: So is what you're attempting to do is create a table where there can be no more than 5 rows for any particular `bcode` and `customer_no` combination?

Comment: I tried to insert multiple rows and checked what happens with INSERTED table using this command SELECT * FROM INSERTED. then I realized inserting rows are step by step inserted to the INSERTED table and it has only one row at a time.

Comment: any away I change the above trigger as below and it works fine. but still I can not understand the problem with above trigger.


CREATE TRIGGER tr_check_accounts_in_accountTBL
ON account FOR  INSERT
AS
BEGIN
 
 SELECT @bcode=bcode,@cusNo=customer_no
 FROM inserted;
 
 SELECT @count=COUNT(a.account_no)
 FROM account a
 WHERE a.bcode=@bcode AND a.customer_no = @cusNo
 print @count;
 
 IF(@count>5)
  rollback transaction
 
END

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever, yes exactly that is what I want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments - normally, `Inserted` can and will contain **multiple rows** and your current trigger cannot deal with that.

But if you know and can guarantee you're only ever going to insert one row at a time - then your trigger still has flaws:

- since you're using `INSTEAD OF INSERT`, in the case where everything is OK, you must actually **do the `INSERT`** - this trigger is run **instead of** the usual SQL insert.... so if all is well, you need to do the insert operation
- also: don't call `COMMIT` in the trigger - it will be handled automatically if everything is OK. Only use `ROLLBACK` to abort an `INSERT` if the situation is not good

You need to use something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_check_accounts_in_accountTBL
ON dbo.Account INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @count int
    DECLARE @bcode int
    DECLARE @cusNo int

    SELECT @bcode = bcode, @cusNo = customer_no
    FROM inserted;

    SELECT @count = COUNT(a.account_no)
    FROM dbo.Account a
    WHERE a.bcode = @bcode AND a.customer_no = @cusNo

    IF(@count <= 5)
        -- all is well, now DO the insert!
        INSERT INTO dbo.Account (account_no, balance, type_code, branch_no, Bcode, customer_no)
           SELECT 
              account_no, balance, type_code, branch_no, Bcode, customer_no
           FROM 
              Inserted
    ELSE
       -- situation is not good -> abort the INSERT
       ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

Also: I would **strongly** recommend **NOT** using `real` for your money values - use `DECIMAL(p, s)` instead! `REAL` is very bad in terms of rounding errors and lack of precision .....

Comment: but there is a logical error, this trigger allows to insert more than 5 accounts to Account table where same bcode and customer_no

Comment: @SelaruSinbath: it allows **6** rows - since you're checking `<= 5` (before the `INSERT` happens) it will **succeed** if there are already 5 rows and will allow a sixth row to be inserted. You need to understand: at the time you're checking for `<= 5`, the new `INSERT` has **NOT HAPPENED** yet! You'll be doing that later on. So if you want to restrict it to 5 rows max, you need to check for `@count < 5` (not `<=`)

Comment: @SelaruSinbath: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.